# Using the input collected from raw_input in Python

Tags: python, raw-input

If I do the following in python,

```
string = raw_input('Enter the value')
```

it will return

> Enter the value

and wait until I enter something into the prompt.

Is there a way to retrieve/collect the input I entered in a variable `string`?

I would like to use the entered value in the following way :

```
if dict.has_key('string'):
          print dict[string]
```

<sub>Note: *I previously made the error of using `raw_string` but I meant to say `raw_input`*</sub>

Answer (score 5):

there's no `raw_string` function in python's stdlib. do you mean raw_input?

```
string = raw_input("Enter the value")     # or just input in python3.0
print(string)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is very confusing ... I'm not familiar with a raw_string function in Python, but perhaps it's application-specific?

Reading a line of input in Python can be done like this:

```
import sys
line = sys.stdin.readline()
```

Then you have that line, terminating linefeed and all, in the variable line, so  you can work with it, e.g. use it has a hash key:

```
line = line.strip()
if line in dict: print dict[line]
```

The first line strips away that trailing newline, since you hash keys probably don't have them.

I hope this helps, otherwise please try being a bit clearer in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want to do?

```
string = raw_input('Enter a value: ')
string = string.strip()
if string in dict: print dict[string]
```

Answer (score 0):

`import readline` provides a full terminal prompt to the `raw_input` function. You get control keys and history this way. Otherwise, it's no better than the `sys.stdin.readline()` option.

```
import readline

while True:
    value = raw_input('Enter a value: ')
    value = value.strip()
    if value.lower() == 'quit': break
```